# How to resume Android app where it was suspended (app not Activity)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

How can I have my Android app resume where it last was, i.e. the Activity in view, etc.?  If I am showing an Activity and press the Home button and then launch my app again it returns to the startup activity.  I'd like it to work like an iPhone app where it suspends in place and resumes back to where the user last was.

Thank you.

Comment: That's actually the default beahaviour...
Are you finishing your activity in onPause, or something like that?
Or do you start your activity with some special flag?

Comment: You have just described the default behavior of an Android application.  You must be finishing some activities or starting them with some different flags which result in the app starting from the begining

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to set [android:alwaysRetainTaskState](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always)="true" for your root activity in the manifest. From the documentation:

> Whether or not the state of the task
>   that the activity is in will always be
>   maintained by the system — "true" if
>   it will be, and "false" if the system
>   is allowed to reset the task to its
>   initial state in certain situations.
>   The default value is "false". This
>   attribute is meaningful only for the
>   root activity of a task; it's ignored
>   for all other activities.
>
> Normally,
>   the system clears a task (removes all
>   activities from the stack above the
>   root activity) in certain situations
>   when the user re-selects that task
>   from the home screen. Typically, this
>   is done if the user hasn't visited the
>   task for a certain amount of time,
>   such as 30 minutes.
>
> However, when this
>   attribute is "true", users will always
>   return to the task in its last state,
>   regardless of how they get there. This
>   is useful, for example, in an
>   application like the web browser where
>   there is a lot of state (such as
>   multiple open tabs) that users would
>   not like to lose.

Comment: I have found that if I long press and tap the application icon it will bring back the application in the last activity shown.  However, if I go to the Applications area of the device and tap the icon then it shows the startup activity.  Why the different behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to save any information you want in your onPause method and check that information in onResume. This will let the app reload any information that was communicated. Some widgets keep state but others don't.

Additionally when an an activity is killed it's onSaveInstanceState method is called. So anything that needs to be stored to persistent memory should be done there.

Answer (score 2):

Although i'm working with Mono for Android i had a similar question.

After some time researching on the web you can setup an Activity to be created using the singleton pattern. This will cause your app to only create one instance and - if you go back to the activity - this will load the last state of that activity for you.

You can do this by configuring the activity with the

`android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"`

and the

```
 android:launchMode="singleTask" //(preffered, or "singleInstance")
```

properties.

Singletask is the best since singleInstance is more suitable for single-activity-based apps.

In my case setting the launchmode made this baby rock as i wanted but i don't know if this is a Mono for Android or Android issue at the root..

**Be aware**: you will need to create an initialize method or something alike if you'd like to create a clean/fresh/new instance of the activity at some point.